# How do I remove top panel on dual screen on secondary monitor?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

How do I remove top bar on secondary monitor??

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not supported. I think it's supposed to be an feature due to the global menu thing.

Comment: State your source, @user15808.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [Multi-Monitor Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/). Turn "Show Panel on additional monitors" to OFF in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gnome extension for this:
[Gnome extension - Hide Top Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in professional use-case like using on corporate-events for presentations or video-playback - if you only have one notebook on the projector and no seamless-switcher. On Windows and Mac you can hide the panel on the second screen and i.e. use black or a company-logo as desktop-background. so if you are working on the presentation, there is a black screen or the company logo showing. It is much neater then having a panel on top of the screen...