# Can I disable title bar on Unity dual screen (second monitor)

Tags: unity

> > **Possible Duplicate:**
> >     [How do I remove top panel on dual screen on secondary monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37691/how-do-i-remove-top-panel-on-dual-screen-on-secondary-monitor)
>
> When I run some applications that use dual screen the top menu bar is
>   still there. Is there any way to remove top menu bar on second screen?

Looking for same solution (problem). I just make the top bar transparent with Unity-Tweak-Tool.

[image]

But the notification area, indicators, power (etc...) still duplicated on both screens.

Sad for presentations.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you can. Unity has lots of weaknesses in multi-monitor setups. That can be considered one of them. The main focus is to make Unity work perfectly for the majority of users first, but many of us have multiple monitors, so these issues are certainly being noticed and worked on.

Answer (score -2):

Keep in mind that dual monitors is completely essential in the business world, when you have to connect a projector or other large screen for presentatios, group conferencing and so on.

And people with laptops who connect it to a nice display when possible, their TV, etc.

Monitor issues are the single biggest source of aggrivation in my Ubuntu-related life today. :)  Note that the problems are much worse with NVidia hardware, and their $*(#awful control panel.  It's like playing Russian Monitor Roulette when you hit that 'apply' button.  It might work, or it might completely mess up both displays, crash Lightdm, still have displays but no titlebars on windows and applications not being responsive, etc. The list is endless and it's a huge mess right now.   It basically requires a reboot right now, IF you managed to get the xorg.conf file configured properly so the second monitor starts up on reboot.