# Ubuntu 20.04: Top "panel" bar for all monitors for Unity

Tags: 20.04, unity, multiple-monitors

I want to display the top "panel" bar on all monitors, instead of just one in Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity desktop.

I have seen suggestions in [other threads](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) to install an extension for Gnome desktop, but I am looking for a solution that works on Unity.

Any suggestions for Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity.

Comment: You may want to correct the Ubuntu version from "Ubuntu 20" to "Ubuntu 20.04".

Comment: Not using Unity myself, but in the past, the situation appears to have been the reverse: there was a top bar on all monitors, that could not be turned off, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/67429/can-i-disable-title-bar-on-unity-dual-screen-second-monitor and furthe.